# Puppet Agent fails sporadically, with either timeout or "Could not find class" error

Tags: centos, puppet

I have `puppet master` running on a Xen dom0, and 3 domUs syncing to it via an hourly crontab `puppet agent --test`.

About 80% of the time, the `puppet agent --test` completes successfully:

```
info: Retrieving plugin
info: Caching catalog for test3
info: Applying configuration version '1333319732'
notice: Finished catalog run in 5.08 seconds
```

The other 20% of the time, it fails midway, with errors such as the following:

```
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER:
     Could not find class iptables for test1 at /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp:1 on node test1
warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

or

```
info: Retrieving plugin
info: Caching catalog for test2
info: Applying configuration version '1333319732'
notice: Finished catalog run in 24.73 seconds
err: Could not send report: Error 500 on SERVER: 

Internal Server Error

private method `gsub' called for WEBrick::HTTPStatus::RequestTimeout:Class

 WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.8.5/2006-08-25) OpenSSL/0.9.8e-rhel5 at
 puppet:8140
```

or

```
info: Retrieving plugin
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: execution expired
warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

or

```
info: Retrieving plugin
info: Caching catalog for test3
info: Applying configuration version '1333319732'
notice: Finished catalog run in 9.47 seconds
err: Could not send report: Error 408 on SERVER: Request Timeout
```

During this time, I've not made any changes to the Puppet configuration — it just sporadically fails.

I'm running puppet-2.7.12 on CentOS, and followed the setup instructions described on http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/agent_master_basic.html.

Any ideas about how I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: Wow... I know what the timeouts are, and I've seen the sporadic "Could not find class" errors before, but the "private method gsub" one's a new one.  You've got a *severely* boned Puppet installation.

Comment: I don't know about *troubleshooting* this but the advice I remember reading was to get away from WEBrick as soon as you have more than one client.  Apache and passenger was the route I took but anything that can serve Ruby should do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several weeks ago, I increased the memory allocation for the virtual machine running `puppet master` by a couple hundred megabytes, and there haven't been any failures since then.

*(That's a strange way of indicating memory is insufficient...)*

Comment: Most likely the server was swapping or getting memory faults. We track our puppet server that way but we have a few more nodes than you. Puppet compiles the manifests for each server before sending them out which eats memory. If you do increase the number of nodes, switch to a different server for running puppet.

Comment: Bingo.  Looks like I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Webrick is monothreaded, and with lousy performance. Beyond 20 servers is relatively low number of configuration items (around 200), you have to change to something else. Use Puppet Rack -- it's much better.